# Installation architecture tab is missing from installshield limited edition visual studio 2013

Tags: architecture, installshield

When I installed **InstallShield Limited Edition 2015** in **Visual Studio 2013**.

But it is giving only 6 tabs. **Installation Architecture tab is missing**. I tried installing many times and even after changing the machine, issue is not solved.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Installshield]

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Nudge, see Urman's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Installation Architecture tab was always effectively disabled in the limited edition. In the videos of older versions that you have seen, the [lock icon](https://youtu.be/HdSuGENg3W4?t=613) indicates this. The reception to these locked items wasn't very positive, so in more recent versions locked items like this were removed instead.

If you do need to specify more than one feature that an end user can choose whether to install, you will need to use another edition of InstallShield or another product.

Answer (score 0):

***Technical Support***: A definite technical support issue, but I do not know whether Installshield provides support for the limited edition. I think it is not sold anymore? Are you sure that view is even included in that edition? Do you see any error messages anywhere? Did you try several different OS versions? Are you using a virtual only?

***Installshield Community***: I would try a better forum for the issue. Specifically Installshield's own community: **http://community.installshield.com**. Or Stefan Kruger's installsite.org's forum: **http://forum.installsite.net**.

---

***COM Registration***: In the realm of "hints": I suppose it could be a COM registration issue, or it could be that that tab is not available in your VS edition - I do not know.

I have noticed that there are some COM / ATL version issues with some Installshield versions, whereby there are incompatible ATL versions being used by the OS and by the Installshield tool respectively. The symptom I have seen have been missing or blank views in Installshield itself. Generally not a problem I have been able to solve.

> Please try to install using a different user account than the one you
>   have to rule out any profile or policy issues. Just try with **a
>   freshly created, local admin account**. Or get someone else to try to install with their account (but a fresh, local admin account would be better).

Comment: currently this is being used for visual studio and they recommend for this. Also I saw on youtube and other sites also they installed the same version but they had the installation architecture tab by default.

Comment: Just to be sure: did you click the arrow at the right?

Comment: yes I tried, there is only 6 tab. By the way installation architecture comes as 3rd tab